# How to apply Difference of Gaussian(DoG) approach to extract pores in fingerprint image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gaussian, feature-detection

I am working on a fingerprint recognition system, I need to extract pores which are present in the ridges.During my research I read that a blob detection technique can separate the pores from the ridges.However when I am applying a Gaussian Filter, it is smoothing the image. Also the DoG results in another similar image. If this is the right approach then where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to apply a gaussian filter with 2 different sets of parameters, then subtract the filters and perform a convolution of the input image with that new filter, i.e. the difference of gaussians.

Here is an example with the coins.png demo image...The code is commented; don't hesitate to play with the parameters to see how that affects the output:

```
clear
clc


Im = imread('coins.png');

[r,c,~] = size(Im);

%// Initialize 3d array containing 3 images.
FilteredIm = zeros(r,c,3);

%// Try with 3 different kernel sizes
GaussKernel = [7 11 15];
figure;
subplot(2,2,1)
imshow(Im);
title('Original image');

TitleText = cell(1,numel(GaussKernel));
%// Apply Gaussian filter with 3 different kernel sizes/sigma values.
for k = 1:numel(GaussKernel)

    %// Kernel sizes change but sigma values stay the same for
    %// simplicity...you can play around with them of course.

    GaussFilt1 = fspecial('Gaussian', GaussKernel(k), 12);
    GaussFilt2 = fspecial('Gaussian', GaussKernel(k), 4);

    %// Subtract the filters
    DiffGauss = GaussFilt1 - GaussFilt2;

    %// Perform convoluton to get filtered image
    FilteredIm(:,:,k) = conv2(double(Im), DiffGauss, 'same');

    %// Display
    subplot(2,2,k+1)

    imshow(FilteredIm(:,:,k));
    TitleText{k} = sprintf('Filtered- Kernel of %i',GaussKernel(k));
    title(TitleText{k});
end
```

Output:

[image]

Now for your application you probably need to play around with the kernel size and sigma parameters provided to `fspecial`. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response, however I am still getting a gray image while my aim is to retain black and white. Extreme low values and high values tend to make the background white and foreground black which  is completely opposite to my input image.

Comment: Is it possible to bring out, only the inside edges of the coin by merging the  the circular boundaries with the background??

Comment: Sorry for late reply. For your 1st question, you might want to take the invert of your image (` ~Image`). For the 2nd case, maybe try to erode the image using a disk structuring element.

Comment: I tried  using erode but it results in a complete black image.

Comment: Is there a way I can encircle the extracted white blobs as per my image and not the other edges?